# How to set position moviepy?

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I want to сhange video resolution and then superimpose it on the picture in the center.

`

```
from moviepy.editor import *



img = ImageClip("image.png")
video2 = VideoFileClip("down.mp4")
video2.set_position(("center", 0.6), relative=True)
video2.subclip().fx(vfx.resize, width=885, height=825)
video2.set_position(("center", 0.6), relative=True)
final = CompositeVideoClip([img, video2]).set_duration(20)

final.write_videofile("finall.mp4", audio=False)
```

`

I tried .set_position(("center", "center")), .set_position((0.5, 0.5)), .set_position(("center", 0.5)), .set_position((500, 500)) and others, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that for just centering a clip you only have to use the following method:

```
set_position("center")
```

You should also be able to have it take two string arguments

```
set_position("center", "top")
```

Additionally, you can adjust the "margin" to get a clip to go up or down a specific number of pixels

```
margin(bottom=100, opacity=0)
```

take a look at this for more

https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/4mvy8k/getting_the_position_of_a_clip/

Answer (score 0):

1. put an image into a composition (a CompositeVideoClip)
2. use "image.set_position((0.5, 0.5), relative=True)" and replace (0.5, 0.5) with any position you want
3. write the video composition to a file.

basically, like this:

```py
img = ImageClip("image.png")

video = CompositeVideoClip([img], duration=5)

img.set_position((0.5, 0.5), relative=True)

video.write_videofile("final.mp4", audio=False)
```